# rest app php "Trying to get property of non-object"

Tags: php

I would need some help on my rest app plz.
I'm trying to understand the reason of this error message "Trying to get property of non-object" but I'm stuck

I commented the following snippet who's manage a formations create form :

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

include_once '../config/database.php';      // Database connection file 
include_once '../objects/formation.php';    // Formation class file

$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

$formation = new Formation($db);            // class Formation              

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));  // Posted datas 

$formation->formation = $data->formation;   // This line return an error : Trying to get property of non-object

// var_dump($data)      return an object(stdClass) with a ["formation"] property
// var_dump($formation) return an object(Formation) with a ["formation"] property

if($formation->createFormation()){
  echo '"Message": "Success"';
  }
  else {
    echo '"Message": "Failed"';
  }
```

I don't understand why the line "$formation->formation = $data->formation;" doesn't work ...

Did I use a wrong syntax ? Any advices ? Thx

Comment: Add the whole `var_dump` exactly as it is.

Comment: Does `$data` have a property `formation`?

Comment: **`$formation->formation = clone $data->formation;`**

Comment: Try `var_dump($data);`. If that's empty, then `var_dump(file_get_contents("php://input"));` It's missing info somewhere.

Comment: @aynber

object(stdClass)#4 (4) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["formation"]=>
  string(4) "test"
  ["commentaire"]=>
  string(3) "com"
  ["active"]=>
  int(1)
}

Comment: @RiggsFolly : Uncaught Error: __clone method called on non-object

Comment: @RiggsFollyI don't think that this question is a duplicate of clone method. The subject would better is that : "What's the correct syntax to affect $data properties to a class properties ?"